# how to extract a single parameter from the response body in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In my `javascript` code I have a part of the function:

```
parseBody: function(body) {
    if (body == '' || body == null) {
        return;
    }

    console.log(body);
    .
    .
    .
```

The body I see in the logs is as follows:

```
<bTransaction accepted="true" cancelled="false"
    xmlns="..."
    xmlns:ns2="..."
    xmlns:ns3="...">
    <serial-no>064946437</serial-no>
    <channel>8888</channel>
    <id>10007756</id>
    <transaction-time>2021-07-07T10:33:19.128-04:00</transaction-time>
    <amount>3.00</amount>
    <details>
        <w-detail addon="false">
            <b-amount>3.00</b-amount>
            <number-of-lots>1</number-of-lots>
            <feature>
                <feature-name>repeat</feature-name>
                <feature-value>true</feature-value>
            </feature>
            <b-data qp="false" played="true" modifiers="many=true, repeat=true">04 10 11 14</b-data>
            <number-of-b>1</number-of-b>
        </w-detail>
    </details>
</bTransaction>
```

I need to print only the value of `qp` from here:

```
<b-data qp="false" played="true" modifiers="many=true, repeat=true">04 10 11 14</b-data>
```

so that I would only see in the console the flag `false`. Could you please help me and tell me what is the best way to parse this whole block of body and get only the value of the `qp` parameter?

I thought about parsing the response by using

```
var bodyXML = $.parseXML(body);
var jqObj = $(bodyXML);
```

but I don't know how to get this value from there either,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
bodyXML.getElementsByTagName("details")[0].getElementsByTagName("b-data")[0].textContent
```

or

```
bodyXML.querySelector("details>w-detail>b-data").textContent
```

For node attribute

```
bodyXML.querySelector("details w-detail b-data").getAttribute("qp")
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and unfortunately it prints only `04 10 11 14` instead of `false` - do you know how to print the proper flag value instead?

Comment: You can extract attribute in same way, modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

const bData = doc.getElementsByTagName('b-data')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

From here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: while trying this solution, I'm getting `xml is not defined` being thrown in the 2nd line - do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Edit name of variable, xml or body or whatever.

Comment: thanks! however now I'm facing the problem with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined`

Comment: Maybe `b-data` doesn't exist, try to debug.
Can write like this const bData = doc.getElementsByTagName('b-data')?.[0]?.childNodes?.[0]?.nodeValue

Comment: Maybe `b-data` doesn't exist, try to debug.
Can write like this const bData = doc.getElementsByTagName('b-data')?.[0]?.childNodes?.[0]?.nodeValue